# ASP.NET(Web Form)でHTML5によるWeb画面開発は可能でしょうか？

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NETでのWeb Form開発を検討してますが、Web Formは、HTML5に対応していますでしょうか？

Comment: 明確には対応していないがある程度対処出来るようです。[ASP.NET Web Forms](https://techinfoofmicrosofttech.osscons.jp/index.php?ASP.NET%20Web%20Forms%20vs%20ASP.NET%20MVC#o66a29b3), [Web開発レポート-HTML5をASP.NET WebフォームアプリケーションやASP.NET MVCアプリケーションに統合する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/may/web-dev-report-integrate-html5-into-existing-asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-applications), [Use HTML 5 and jQuery in WebForms](https://www.codemag.com/article/1411051/Use-HTML-5-and-jQuery-in-WebForms), [ASP.net webforms with HTML5](https://forums.asp.net/t/1932816.aspx?ASP+net+webforms+with+HTML5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Web Formは、HTML5に対応していますでしょうか？

Yes か No どっちかと聞かれたら答えは Yes です。ただ、細かいところまで 100% 対応しているかは質問者さんが考えている HTML5 が何かによると思います。

宣言を <!DOCTYPE html> にするとかの基本的なところは VS2019 など新しい IDE のテンプレートで作るプロジェクトでは対応していますが、サーバーコントロールを ASP.NET が html コードにレンダリングする際、デフォルトではなく別の形にする必要があるというような場合は難しいかもしれません。

具体例を挙げてもらえると、具体的なレスがつきやすいと思います。